# How to call stored procedure in pentaho reporting designer?

Tags: pentaho

I am new to learn pentaho reporting tool,

Can anyone tell me how to call stored procedure in pentaho report designer.
In Report designer we have not seen the directly stored procedure .

How will i find out and call stored procedure in report designer ?

Answer (score 1):

If your database is MS SQL server, convert your Store Procedure to Function with table as its  result.

Answer (score 0):

if your db is postgres then you can simply write following query: 
Select * from  As ( ,....);
Here  is the columns that you need in report.

Answer (score -1):

CALL SCHEMA.STORED_PROCEDURE (Parameters you wish to pass in)

CALL SCHEMA.STORED_PROCEDURE (Param1, Param2, Param3)

- This is with a db2 database but syntax similar for others.

Comment: Pentaho report does not support this syntax; this is just SQL syntax reference.